# Email failures in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to send mail using below code

```
Mail::send(new ContactUs($request));
if(Mail::failures()){
   return response()->json(['result' => 1]);  
}
else {
   return response()->json(['result' => 0]);  
}
```

But I am not getting any response from `Mail::failures()` section.

Comment: It should return an array, so your if condition needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks @BramVerstraten. Could you please say about structure of the array ? Do you have any link ?

Comment: You can simply do `count(Mail::failures()) > 0`, this will work. `Mail::failures()` is an array of Email addresses which are failed, You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_failures. @abuabu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Mail::failures()` you can use `!empty(Mail::failures())` or `count(Mail::failures()) > 0`.

`Mail::failures()` Function returns an array of Email addresses which are failed.

> array failures()
>
> Get the array of failed recipients.
>
> Return Value
>
> array

You can read it here: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_failures